# Finding the interpolation with user input

Tags: c, function, char, interpolation, do-while

I made some revisions to the algorithm, and get a value (though it is incorrect) in the function, but the return value refuses to send it back to the main function. Also, I cannot get they yes no portion of the code that ask for the program to rerun to function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <float.h>
/*Prototype for functions used*/
float getdistance(float[], float[], float, int);
float printvalue(float);

int main()
{

      int maxtime = 18;
      float usertime = 0;
      char reiteration;
      char y, n;
      int reit_choice = 0;
      float interpolation = 0.0;
      float time_arr[]={0,3,5,8,10,12,15,18};
      float distance_arr[]={2,5.2,6,10,10.4,13.4,14.8,18};
      do
      { 
       printf("Please enter a number between 0 and 18 for the starting time:");
       scanf("%f", &usertime, "\b");
        while(usertime <0 || usertime >18)
       {
          printf("The value you have entered is not valid, please enter a value between 1 and 18");
          scanf("%f", &usertime, "\b");
       }/*End of data verification loop*/
       getdistance(time_arr, distance_arr, usertime, maxtime);
       printf("%f", interpolation);
       printvalue(interpolation);

       system("pause");

       printf("would you like to check another time?(y/n)");
       scanf("%c[y n]", &reiteration, "\b");
       while(reiteration!='y' || reiteration!='n')
       {
          printf("Please enter either y for yes or n for no");
          scanf("%c", &reiteration, "\b");
       }/*End of choice verification loop*/
       if(reiteration = 'y')
       {
         reit_choice = 1;
       }
       else
       {
         reit_choice = 0;
       }
}/*End of do loop*/
while(reit_choice);

}/*End of main loop*/

float getdistance(float time_arr[], float distance_arr[], float usertime, int maxtime)
{
   int index=0;
   float interpolation = 0;

   for(index; usertime > time_arr[index]; index++)
   {
      if(usertime<3)
      {
         break;
      }
   }/*End of value assignment for loop*/
   interpolation = (time_arr[index]) + (((time_arr[index +1] -     time_arr[index])/(distance_arr[index +1] - distance_arr[index])) * (usertime - distance_arr[index]));
   printf("%f", interpolation);
   return interpolation;
}/*End of distance calculation loop*/

float printvalue(float interpolation)
{
   printf("The interpolation was %f", interpolation);
}/*End of screen print loop*/
```

Comment: Try running your code through a debugger and check intermediate values to better localize the error. Alternatively, print the intermediate values. Also note that the question is ambiguous: There are lots of ways to interpolate between numbers.

Comment: My main issue is that I keep getting zeros for my values, and the loop that is asking for the user to continue ignores keyboard input.

Comment: can you please provide the algorithm for finding interpolation?

Comment: interpolation = (time_arr[curpos]) + (((time_arr[curpos +1] - time_arr[curpos])/(distance_arr[index +1] - distance_arr[index])) * (usertime - distance_arr[curpos]));

Comment: Even with the knowledge of that interpolation algorithm, I still won't take the time to debug your code and write an answer. The code example contains too much dead weight, mostly the string parsing. Please provide a minimal example of the wrong code, and what you'd expect it to do. That way, you show at least minimal effort in writing the question, might discover the error yourself, and make the question useful for further readers.

Comment: I cleaned it up, but It would seem that the whole code would be necessary if someone is trying to solve this problem as well. I get some of the correct values in the calculation function, but the value does not make it back to the main.

Comment: Can you also provide a expected input and output?

Comment: You could just hardcode the usertime in `int main()`, inline the code of printvalue(), etc. Plenty of ways to improve the example code. Also, BTW the comment `/*End of main loop*/` should be `/* End of main function */`, and is pretty superfluous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for 0 output is

```
getdistance(time_arr, distance_arr, usertime, maxtime);
```

in *int main()*  function you're calling the function *getdistance* which calculates the interpolation value and returns the value, But in main function the **returned value is not assigned to the variable interpolation** . so you've to modify the code as

```
interpolation = getdistance(time_arr, distance_arr, usertime, maxtime);
printvalue(interpolation);
```

Which will print the output